# Select span child of this in jquery

Tags: jquery

```html
      <div class="card-footer d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center px-0 pt-0 pb-3">
                 <div class="px-4 pt-3"> <a id="likes" href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-muted d-inline-flex align-items-center align-middle" data-abc="true"> <i  class="fa fa-heart text-danger"></i>&nbsp; <span  class="align-middle"> {{$preguntas["likes"]}}  </span> </a> <span class="text-muted d-inline-flex align-items-center align-middle ml-4"> <i class="fa fa-eye text-muted fsize-3"></i>&nbsp; <span class="align-middle">{{$preguntas["views"]}}</span> </span> </div>
                 <div class="px-4 pt-3"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="ion ion-md-create"></i>&nbsp; Reply</button> </div>
             </div>
```

I am trying to select this element with jquery and I am having some problems. I tried nth child, next and with no results.

[image: html]

Any Idea? Thanks

```
      <div class="card-footer d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center px-0 pt-0 pb-3">
                 <div class="px-4 pt-3"> <a id="likes" href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-muted d-inline-flex align-items-center align-middle" data-abc="true"> <i  class="fa fa-heart text-danger"></i>&nbsp; <span  class="align-middle"> {{$preguntas["likes"]}}  </span> </a> <span class="text-muted d-inline-flex align-items-center align-middle ml-4"> <i class="fa fa-eye text-muted fsize-3"></i>&nbsp; <span class="align-middle">{{$preguntas["views"]}}</span> </span> </div>
                 <div class="px-4 pt-3"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="ion ion-md-create"></i>&nbsp; Reply</button> </div>
             </div>
```

$(this).children('span:nth(1)')

$(this).find(':second-child').text()

I capture this when I click on the A element

```
$("#likes").click(function(event){



$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
     dataType: "json",
     url: '/darLike/'+$("#hiddenquestion").val(),
 })

 .done(function(response){



 })

.fail(function(response){
    console.log(  $(this).find(':second-child').text()); 
});
```

});

I've tried this but nothing

Comment: Please include the HTML as code in the question, as well as your jQuery attempts so far.

Comment: Edited, sorry for it

Comment: How are you defining `this`?

Comment: Use code Snippet to explain your issue.

Comment: The `this` on `.fail` is the response not the `#likes` element

Answer (score 0):

Like akaBase said, when you use this on .fail you get the responde not the element.

var elemento = $(this);

I got the element and later on fail used this:

$(elemento).children().first().next().text()

And it worked!